# Let $X$ be a non-empty set, $A \subseteq X$. Decide the set $\mathcal M(\mathcal{E})$ of $\mathcal{E}$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measureable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set, $A \subseteq X$. Decide the set $\mathcal M(\mathcal{E})$ of $\mathcal{E}$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measureable functions $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ in each of the following cases:

(a) $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal P(X)$: I've decided that $\mathcal M(\mathcal{E})=\{f : f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R\}$ in this case.

(b) $\mathcal{E} = \{X, \emptyset \}$: I've decided that $\mathcal M(\mathcal{E})=\{f : f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R \ \text {is constant}\}$ in this case.

(c) $\mathcal{E} = \{X, A, A^C, \emptyset\}$: I've really no idea how to prove this. I know that if $\mathcal D$ is a generator of $\epsilon$ then it is enough to prove $f^{-1}(D) \in \epsilon \ \forall D \in \mathcal D$, but until now I'd no luck in applying this.

Comment: The first two are correct. For (c), try and show that the measurable functions are exactly those who are constant on $A$ and constant on $A^c$.

Comment: How do you get the idea that this is the case ? :)

Comment: Unrelated: In case you meant to write $\mathcal{E}$ instead of $\epsilon$ as the sigma-algebra, you can use `\mathcal{E}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be $\mathcal{E}$-measurable. We claim that $f$ is on the form
$$
f=a\mathbf{1}_A+b\mathbf{1}_{A^c} \tag{1}
$$
for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. If $f$ only takes on one value, then $f$ is on the form in $(1)$ with $a=b$. So assume that $f$ takes on at least two distinct values and call them $a$ and $b$. Then
$$
\{x\in X\mid f(x)=a\}=f^{-1}(\{a\})\in \{\varnothing,A,A^c,X\}
$$
since $\{a\}$ is a Borel set. But it can't be $\varnothing$ because we know there are at least one element $x$ such that $f(x)=a$ and it can't be $X$ since we are assuming that $f$ takes on at least two distinct values. So assume that $f^{-1}(\{a\})=A$, then a similar argument shows that $f^{-1}(\{b\})=A^c$ or in other words $f$ is of the form in $(1)$.

Now you just have to show that all functions of the form in $(1)$ are $\mathcal{E}$-measurable.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your proof also show that there can be at most $2$ distinct elements, since any other must be equal to $a$ or $b$ right ?

Comment: Yes, all elements of $A$ are mapped to $a$ and all elements of $A^c$ are mapped to $b$.